# Is it possible to run test code written by other languages in flutter?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, webview, appium

I am trying to automate my webview app by using Appium, but code that I exported from Appium is written in java. Is it possible to test flutter app by test code written in other languages, not in dart?

Comment: i'm curios to know

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: You can use Appium in conjunction with Selenium. I think that should work. See: http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/

If what the test framework does is to integrate with, or emulate, a browser, and manipulate the DOM in order to test, and

If your Dart application only manipulates the DOM to generate a web view -- e.g., it would work in a regular browser without using plugins,

Then yes, you can use such a tool (like Selenium) to test a Dart app.

The caveat here is, if you are using a WebView to embed your app in a mobile app framework, then these tools will have to have the ability to open an app on a mobile device to access the WebView.

If you can create an alternate scaffolding for your application, such that it can also run in a browser, not only as an embedded WebView in a mobile app, then the tools needed to test it are only simple web app testing frameworks.

This is generally a good approach if you can get faster feedback deploying to a web server and running your tests, than packaging the app and pushing it to a connected device.

It doesn't obviate the need to test in the WebView as there are often differences between browser capabilities as embedded in a WebView versus in a desktop browser, but any differences found would be purely based on the capabilities of the browser, as opposed to problems in your Dart logic.